# Conversion of bitmap into jpeg in android

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg

Is there any way to convert a android.graphics.Bitmap instance into jpeg in android?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try with [compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) method like:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outStream);
```

---

Here is a sample program : [compressing-a-bitmap-to-jpg-format-android-example](http://android.okhelp.cz/compressing-a-bitmap-to-jpg-format-android-example/)

Comment: Thanks for help Imran, i got the result. Earlier also, I tried with the above method, but I was not getting desired output. Thats why, I posted my query here. But now, I rectified my mistake and its working fine.